# How can I create a deeper level of detail page for single list content in HUGO

Tags: hugo

I’m building our job posting pages with Hugo. So we will have a “Join Us” section with the list of job postings there and then we will need a detailed page for each job post, something like /join/software_engineer/. Hugo works well for this part, I created a section page template and single page template, with all the job posts in the content folder.

But now we need a deeper level of the detail page, like /join/software_engineer/submit/ to submit the resume and other info. The detail page may look very similar for every job post and will need some info from the single list content and a structured URL. Is there any way I can achieve this in a “HUGO way”? (Right now I’m coding the submit section with a modal, but still very curious if this kind of detail page is achievable.)

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

if you like to go deeper your last folder needs to have an _index.md file (note the underscore). Then set the type in your frontmatter and create a custom layout e.g.

type: software_engineer

layouts/software_engineer/list.html

I have a site where I go many levels deep and that works well.